# Check if Clipboard locked or catch exception

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, clipboard

I've made multiple attempts to solve this, and multiple google searches to find a solution that would fit, but nothing seems right.

User32 methods will let you lock or unlock the clipboard, but I just want to check if it is unlocked. I don't want my application to interfere with other applications using the clipboard. Usually it seemed to be office that blocks this, so I'm currently checking for these applications.

The only reason I need to do that, is because despite the try/catch, my application still crashes, and does not throw any exception here or in my main method (see excerpt below).

So I need a suggestion for either how to check the clipboard for if it is locked or not, or how to actually catch an exception when the clipboard is locked.

Second thread:

```
private static string GetCurrentText()
        {
            try
            {
                if (!Process.GetProcessesByName("winword.exe").Any() && !Process.GetProcessesByName("excel.exe").Any() && !Process.GetProcessesByName("powerpnt.exe").Any() && !Process.GetProcessesByName("msaccess.exe").Any() && Clipboard.ContainsText())return Clipboard.GetText(); 
                else return "";
            }
            catch { return ""; }
        }
```

Main Thread:

```
 try
                {
                    Application.ThreadException += Application_ThreadException;
                    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
                    Application.Run(new frmMain());
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    clsDeBugNotification.displayError(e);
                }
```

Comment: You can't have an application crash without an exception. Even in the worst case (where the runtime crashes without any chance for managed code to run) you'd find the details of that error in the application event log. What are the actual details of the crash, and what makes you think it's due to a locked clipboard?

Comment: Just FYI, when you use `Process.GetProcessesByName(...)` don't include `.exe`. If `.exe` is included then no processes will be found.

Comment: when the function isn't called, the application runs stable. As soon as I reintroduce this function, the application has risk of crashing. It might be seconds, it might be hours, but there is the risk it will crash.

Looking into the applog (thank you for that, i was unaware that windows was actually logging anything) there is:
```
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
```

Comment: I've never seen an Office application *locking* the ClipBoard *on its own*. Perhaps you mean it *needs to access the ClipBoard*, at some point. If you get an exception while accessing the ClipBoard, it may be caused by your code, because of the way it handles what it gets out of it. Or you have installed a *rogue* app (Shell extension, maybe), that temporarily Opens the ClipBoard and doesn't close it, for its own use. But I can say it's a common thing.

Comment: no other application installed. 

It was/is my running hypothesis that it is office since it does allow you to track items in the clipboard, similar to how Win10 does if you are allowed to turn that feature on. Unfortunately the app crash is sporadic, and I haven't been able to narrow down the exact cause or similar conditions between crashes.

Comment: "Second thread:" - does this mean that you are running that code on a secondary thread?  If so, is the ApartmentState of that thread `ApartmentState.STA`?  ClipBoard functions must run for a STA thread.  Default ThreadPool threads are MTA.

Comment: yes, thankfully winforms only lets you run STA

Comment: "yes" to what? It is running on a secondary thread? "winforms only lets you run STA" - Winform must run a STA thread, but it does not prevent you from using MTA threads.

Comment: Hmm, might have to look into using MTA if I ever have a benefit to do so in the future. Based on previous attempts to do so, several years ago when I first started to explore multiple threads, MTA failed to work properly.